# instantiating a class using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm pretty new to composer and working with php classes.
I've installed the following class:
[Packgist php usps class](https://packagist.org/packages/binarydata/usps-php-api)

I`ve updated composer and uploaded the vendor/class folder do my server.

After including the autoload, I don't know how to instantiate the class.
I've tried:

```
use Dinarydata\USPS\USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator;
or
use USPS\USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator
```

I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class "USPS\USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator" not found in /home/shiplim/public_html/bkend/debug.php:5
```

So, my question is: How do I know whats the right way to instatiate a Class once I've installed it via Composer. This is where I always get stucked. I would like the unsertand the logic behind it so I can work with different packages from packgist.

I really appreciate any help!

Ps: this is how my code looks like:

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
use USPS\USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator;

$delivery = new USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator('xxx');
```

Comment: The demo is here: https://github.com/binary-data/USPS-php-api/blob/master/demos/servicedeliverycalculator.php. The class does not appear to be namespaced.

Comment: So I need to use require_once instead of "use" ?

Comment: I tried including the file but got error:
Uncaught Error: Class "USPS\USPSBase" not found in /home/shiplim/public_html/bkend/vendor/binarydata/usps-php-api/src/USPS/USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator.php:

Comment: The class itself actually seem to be namespaced: https://github.com/binary-data/USPS-php-api/blob/master/src/USPS/USPSServiceDeliveryCalculator.php. However, the PSR-4 paths in their `composer.json` file are pointing to the wrong folder (should be `src/` but is only `/`), which makes composer to trying to load it from the wrong place, so this is an issue with the package, not your code. You can ofc require the class(es) yourself instead, just make sure you also require any other class it uses/depends on from the same package.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, can you give me an example of how should I do it?

Comment: Do what? Use `require`?

Comment: My 3rd comment showed what happened when I tried require

Comment: Like I said, _"just make sure you also require any other class it uses/depends on from the same package."_ If you get class "not found" for any other class in that package (like `USPS\USPSBase`, then you need to require those as well. I would personally not rely on a package that doesn't allow you to add issues in their github repo.

Comment: Keep in mind that the repository you've linked to has seen its last activity more then seven years ago. There might be other problems arising if you overcome the first problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my question is: How do I know whats the right way to instatiate a Class once I've installed it via Composer. This is where I always get stucked. I would like the unsertand the logic behind it so I can work with different packages from packgist.

That are many questions at once, so let's go through:

> How do I know whats the right way to instatiate a Class once I've installed it via Composer.

You know that by reviewing each individual package that you consider to require prior use. First of all consult the usage documentation and otherwise code-review each package (which is recommended for each package version you make use of, not that I would expect many updates for this package specifically, just that you get the right feeling).

Why that? Because you consider to make use of code you've not written your own, therefore you need to review it, otherwise you don't know what it does.

Additionally this is because there is no formal requirement of any kind to define a composer package. Or, perhaps there are some minuscule ones for those packages published on Packagist, but specifically for the topic on how to require (use) them, they are out of scope. C.f. [composer-validate(1)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#validate)

> This is where I always get stuck.

We can't take the work out of your hands. If you get stuck reviewing those packages, and it includes to get them working within review, it is normally a sign to not depend on such packages. Drop them. Trust your capability, and if you get stuck, skip those dependencies, don't use them.

They don't work for you. That is the best review you can do.

> I would like the understand the logic behind it so I can work with different packages from packagist.

I can perfectly understand your wish, but as written, every project is different and therefore is every package. There is no general answer to such a question.

And if you allow me the comment, the one you've picked is especially different as others have already commented. Just kill it with fire, it's the wrong scenario to ask about how things are done in general with a package that has configuration issues like this one has.

Take their license word by word and drop it into the dumpster.

Instead of considering this library in any different way, in regard of your actual question:

- Read the Composer documentation on their website to learn about it.
- PHP documentation covers this in the [*Autoloading Classes*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) section

But then again, you still need to review the package *and* master your own Composer configuration to get this specific package working.

This may, at the end of the day, enable your to handle all of the packages on packgist, but again, if you're puzzled about getting stuck with this one, don't. Try another one to get stuck with first.

Just my 2 cents, YMMV.